# Selenium C# - How to click on icon elements on a website

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am in the process creating a test on the page linked below. However I am having trouble being able to click on the first icon "1-2 Bedroom House". If anyone has any ideas on how to use Selenium C# to select any of the icons on this page, then I can use that same method for all of them.

Thanks in advance.

https://www.estatesales.net/companies/request?returnUrl=%2Fcompanies

---

I have tried a few ways, but still nothing is working.

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("es-icon-home")).Click();    
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='1-2 Bedroom House']"));    
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//es-icon[contains(@aria-label, '1-2 Bedroom House')]")).Click();
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.